# handleTeamsSigninVerifyState getting hit when teams calls but response is 501

Tags: botframework

Package: "botbuilder": "^4.7.2"

we have extended TeamsActivityHandler ..
class TeamsGithubBot extends TeamsActivityHandler

and inside that we have

```
protected async handleTeamsSigninVerifyState(
    context: TurnContext, query: SigninStateVerificationQuery,
  ): Promise<void> 
{our code here}
```

when team calls our message handler with

```
"name": "signin/verifyState",
    "type": "invoke",
```

I can see/debug that our code gets hit, but response to the teams call is 501 Not Implemented

any pointers on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to the lastest botbuilder package (4.9.2 as of June 2020)

When a `signin/verifyState` invoke arrives at the bot, the magic code should be verified with a call to `adapter.getUserToken`.  If valid, the bot should send an activity of type `invokeResponse` and value with `StatusCode.OK`  Example code to do this can be found in the sdk's [OAuthPrompt](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/src/prompts/oauthPrompt.ts#L355):

```
token = await this.getUserToken(dc, code);
if (token !== undefined) {
    await dc.context.sendActivity({ type: 'invokeResponse', value: { status: 200 } });
} else {
    await dc.context.sendActivity({ type: 'invokeResponse', value: { status: 404 } });
}
```

This invokeResponse will be written to the request body.  If an invokeResponse is not found in turnState after the turn is complete, a NotImplemented exception is thrown.